# how to create bar chart and pie chart in asp.net 2.0 using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create asp.net 2.0 pie chart and bar chart

Answer (score 7):

You can try beautiful and attractive Silverlight Bar and Pie Chart from [Visifire](http://visifire.com). [Visifire](http://visifire.com) is the best choice if you really want to concentrate on looks, clarity while creating presentation or report. Also [Visifire](http://visifire.com) works with all versions of asp.net.

Visifire Bar Chart Gallery: http://visifire.com/silverlight_bar_charts_gallery.php

Visifire Column Chart Gallery: http://visifire.com/silverlight_2d_column_charts_gallery.php

Visifire Pie Chart Gallery: http://visifire.com/silverlight_pie_doughnut_charts_gallery.php

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The MS [Charting Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)?

Comment: i found it rather complex to get started with but definitely nice and powerful

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to build complex and interactive charts you could try Google Chart, it's super easy...

example:

```
<img src="https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World" />
```

produce:

[image]

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own Generic Handler (.ashx) that generates an Image of your Bar Chart/Pie Chart as a Bitmap using System.Drawing and saves it to the Response.OutputStream if a) you really want to make life hard for yourself or b) really need to customise the output in detail

Much better to use one of the Controls recommended by the other guys

Comment: The Bitmap etc classes are not supported for use on a web server; see the caution block here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx

Comment: that only applies to Web and Windows Services, a Generic Handler is simply part of a Web Application.  I've never had any issues with this

Comment: just read some more related stuff to that and MS class an ASP.Net Web Application as a Service, my bad

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Microsoft Charting you can also get good components from

1. [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com)
2. [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com)
3. [DotNetCharting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For a different approach than the MS Chart Control or other components would be to use to use the Microsoft Report Viewer control and design a report (locally or via reporting services) that way.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended:  http://www.simplechart.net/

Answer (score 0):

[ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/)?
Examples:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recomend fusion charts. This API make things very easy to implement.

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/
[image]

regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no question about it the clear #1 choice for me has been to use the MS Chart controls that have builds for both the .NET 2.0 and 4.0 Frameworks. Actually the controls were originally aquired from Dundas by Microsoft so the similarities exist, but the MS Chart controls are free!! They exist in the System.Web.DataVisualization namespace.

I have been using them for about 3 years now, and the extensive documentation and samples make creating the charts a BREEZE in ASP.NET. Take a look at the links below to get started:

**Samples Environment for Microsoft Chart Controls** (downloadable code helps a lot!):
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

**Getting Started (Chart Controls):**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753.aspx